# Notation: should Markov chains steps be noted by uppercase or lowercase letters?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, random-variables

I'm reading the chapter about perfect sampling of the "Monte Carlo Statistical Methods" by Robert and Casella, 2004.

I've got an issue about notation, when they talk about random mappings, they say
$$
\theta^{(t)} = \psi(\theta^{(t)},u_t)
$$
should those $\theta^{(t)}$ be treated as uppercase or lowercase letter? I'm asking because I'm writing an essay about that topic and I want to use, instead of $\theta$, $x$ or $X$. I've been used to use capital $X$ to denote it, since it is a random variable, but I think it may result in a too heavy notation.

I'm confused about the use of $X$ and $x$. I now that, basically, $X$ is a random variable and $x$ a realization, but often in statistics lowercase letters are used anyway in a similar fashion as uppercase letters. What notation should I stick on?

Comment: I'm not sure I have an authority to cite (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but although I generally tend to see $X$ (e.g.) for the random variable, and $x$ as a value possibly taken on by $X$, that isn't universal and there is a notable minority that use lower-case letters for random variables.

Comment: The convention of using caps for random variables is an extremely useful *teaching device*, and one should use it consistently in a first course. Later, when "almost everything" is a random variable, lower case looks better.

Comment: Symbols for random variables differ widely--from author to author, specialty to specialty, and also (perhaps most remarkably) from country to country. In the US, the conventions you and @BrianTung mention are common. So you can correctly use any consistent system of notation you find convenient, but you would be wise to consider your target audience and try to use notation they will find familiar and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In fact my real problem is that the use of $X$ or $x$ may depend on contest, and I'm striving to get consistency in my own notation.
I know I'm being very vague, I may consider the idea to express in a clearer way my doubts.
The fact is that I've seen that in statistics and Monte Carlo methods the boundaries in notation are not that clear, and in fact in a course on statistical inference I got quite confused about the difference in lower/uppercase letters and, at some time, I think the professor itself got lost.